# wakelock is missing permission but i set it in the manifest

Tags: android, permissions, android-wake-lock

I am trying to use the wakelock feature but when I run my app i get an exception saying
    **java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10057 nor current process has android.permission.WAKE_LOCK.**  I copied the exact permission from the android website so I have no idea what could be wrong.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".secondscreen"></activity> <!--this allows for multiple screens -->
    <activity android:name=".processing"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".thirdscreen"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".fourthscreen"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".rewrite"></activity>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

</application>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your `<uses-permission>` elements to appear before the `<application>` element:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".secondscreen"></activity> <!--this allows for multiple screens -->
    <activity android:name=".processing"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".thirdscreen"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".fourthscreen"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".rewrite"></activity>

</application>
```

Comment: Yeah, and write your activities with a capital letter :)

Comment: ok ill try that.  I was stumped because the other 2 permissions worked